# Scala's Parallel Collections vs. Spark Futures vs. `SparkContext.parallelize()`

Tags: scala, apache-spark

#### Task

I would like to spark-submit a Spark application with multiple independent jobs. These jobs can be ran in parallel. Ideally, I'd like to not only use the multiple cores of my driver node, but all the resources available in the entire cluster.

I found 3 potential solutions online, but I'm confused as to which one is the more appropriate/idiomatic approach. Can someone explain to me which approach is best suited for my task?

##### 1. Using Scala's native parallel collection

```
(1 to 100).toList.par
  .foreach(...)
```

##### 2. Using Spark Futures

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

val futureA = Future { ... }
val futureB = Future { ... }

Await.result(futureA, Duration.inf)
Await.result(futureB, Duration.inf)
```

##### 3. Using `sc.parallelize()`

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4,5,6))
rdd.foreach(...)
```

Comment: Spark doesn't have futures.  Also, what are the jobs (e.g. CPU bound, I/O bound, etc.)?

Comment: My jobs are primarily CPU bound. The idea of using Futures in Spark was taken from this presentation https://www.databricks.com/session/parallelizing-with-apache-spark-in-unexpected-ways

Comment: For CPU bound, there won't really be a benefit to using parallel collections or futures (unless you really care about fairness between the jobs/tasks, though in that case, spark might not be the best fit)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the jobs independently in Spark, you can go to FAIR schedular.

**Configuring the FAIR schedular:**

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(...).setAppName(...)
conf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
```

**References:**

1. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application
2. https://supergloo.com/spark/spark-fair-scheduler-example/